# React MultiSelect dropdown showing inside the popup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, frontend

Am using react-multi-select-component.
When I click the dropdown, the dropdown list goes under the div. I need to position the absolute and proper responsive view.
[image]

```
import MultiSelect from "react-multi-select-component";

<MultiSelect
options={options}
value={selectedValue}
onChange={onValueChanged}
label`your text`ledBy="Select"
filterOptions={customSearch}
```

dropdown needs to be position properly

Comment: the dropdown looks to be inside a modal that has `overflow: hidden`. You need to place the dropdown outside the container with hidden overflow, possibly using a React portal

Comment: In my project i need dropdown inside the popup. I tried overflow: hidden but getting same issues. dropdown list go under the popup.